# servlets/jsp - FORM authentication when there is no roles to use in security-constraint

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, servlets

I´m tried to create a FORM authentication but I dont need any role.

The pattern I want to block is "/numbers" so I try:

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
   <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login?erro=true</form-error-page>
   </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>Numeros da sorte</display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Numeros da sorte</web-resource-name>
      <description/>
      <url-pattern>/numbers</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

but it doesnt work because it allows everyone to /numbers without ask for authentication, so if I put some role there, it start working.

There is a way to control authorization without role (just with the act of authentication) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you need something else in addition to configurations in web.xml.

In web.xml, using auth-constraint element, you specify the role, say, admin, that can access the protected resource. And then, in the application server, you map all authenticated users to admin role. By doing this mapping, we assign admin role to all authenticated users. Because all authenticated users have admin role, these users can access the protected resource.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to NOT use roles (I mean no workarounds). Thanks anyway!